# Expected Value with probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

A fair coin is flipped 82 times. What is the expected number of times that a flip of tails is followed immediately by two consecutive flips of heads?

The answer is 10 and I got 10.25. Could someone give a try on this? Thanks

Comment: How did you obtain this value? I'm asking because it could be that there's just a small tweak in your calculations that you should make. By showing your own work, you make this a lot easier for us. Thanks!

Comment: Pr(coin = tail) = 1/2 , Pr(coin = 2 consecutive head) =1/2*1/2 = 1/4 so 1/2*1/4 * 82 = 10.25

Answer (score 2):

A tail followed by $2$ consecutive heads - there are $80$ possible starting positions (you cannot start this sequence in 81st or 82nd toss).

So Expected Number should be $ = \frac{80}{2^3} = 10$.

I think you made a mistake of taking $82$ possible starting positions.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot :)